# Recyclerview not updating rows correctly when removing data from arraylist?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

my `RecyclerView` contains Text and Delete Button when delete is clicked specific row will be deleted from ArrayList

```
                pending.remove(p);// pending is arraylist
```

after this updating  `RecyclerView` by calling this function which is inside `Adapter`

```
swap(pending);
```

`public void swap(ArrayList<DownloadingActivity.scheduleListType> newList) {
            if (pendingList != null) {
                pendingList.clear();
                pendingList.addAll(newList);
            } else {
                pendingList = newList;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }`

but the problem is that correct item deleted successfully from `ArrayList` **pending** but on RecyclerView wrong update is displayed.

if i delete second item from array list **pending** but in RecyclerView updated 
deleted item is last 
when activity is reloaded then values in `RecyclerView` are showing correctly

**searched lot of about it  but did not found any way to solve**

Answer (score 2):

Instaead of using `swap()` to delete the item from your array list and adding them back into diffrent array list, I will suggest that you use [`notifyItemRemoved`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int)) in your adapter. So, your adapter will look like below.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java :**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DownloadingActivity.scheduleListType> p = pendingList.get(position);
     //....
     //....

    holder.deleteBnt.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           pendingList.remove(p);
           notifyItemRemoved(position)
       }
    })
}
```

Comment: @Multidots_Solutions **pending** is Arraylist i am using in Main class and passing it to Adapter to **pendingList** from which list i have to delete row because i am deleting from **pending** which is Main class`s list and also Adapter class is subclass of Main

Comment: pending is Arraylist i am using in Main class and passing it to Adapter to pendingList from which list i have to delete row because i am deleting from pending which is Main class`s list and also Adapter class is subclass of Main

Comment: pending is Arraylist i am using in Main class and passing it to Adapter to pendingList from which list i have to delete row because i am deleting from pending which is Main class`s list and also Adapter class is subclass of Main 
 4
@Multidots